# Does $S^4$ have a "symplecto-homeomorphic" structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, open-problems

The 4-sphere cannot be a symplectic manifold. In particular, it does not admit an atlas whose transition maps are symplectomorphisms $(\mathbb{R}^4,\omega_\text{std})\to(\mathbb{R}^4,\omega_\text{std})$. Eliashberg-Gromov proved that if the $C^0$-limit of symplectomorphisms is a diffeomorphism, then it is
a symplectomorphism. We can now ask about the next best thing:

**Does $S^4$ have a** *symplectohomeomorphic* **structure, i.e. are there charts (equipped with the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{R}^4$) whose transition maps are homeomorphisms that are $C^0$-limits of symplectomorphisms?**

(This question may have originated from Alan Weinstein, who told me it after conversations concerning symplectic rigidity.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an open question--or at least I've heard it referred to as such during this calendar year by multiple people who work on C^0 symplectic topology.

Comment: I completely agree with what Mike said.